# Cannot Schedule an Object that Extends BukkitRunnable a Second Time after Canceling

Tags: scheduler, bukkit

So it seems that I can't schedule an object that extends bukkitrunnable again even though the first scheduled instance is canceled.

for example, the following code is executed when the Player right clicks

```
try {
    blizzard.cancel();
}
finally {
    blizzard.runTaskTimer(Main.plugin, 0, 1);
}
```

Where blizzard is an object that extends BukkitRunnable

The first time runs just fine but never runs again no matter how many times I right click. What am I doing wrong?

**Each player can have their own blizzard object. When a player right clicks with a hoe in hand, Blizzard drops a snowball at a random location around that player. Blizzard drops one snowball every run command and runs until it reaches a set number of runs. Then blizzard cancels itself. However, scheduling Blizzard to run while it is already running throws an IllegalStateException, meaning I have to cancel the current Blizzard to schedule it to run again. The problem is that doing so doesn't seem to properly schedule Blizzard to run again - it only runs the very first time it is scheduled.

Comment: It looks like your canceling the timer and then starting it again... Why not just start it once? You also may want to try using different instances of `blizzard`. What is your desired output? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The task throws an illegalstatexception if the task is not running so it won't be canceled if it hasn't already been set to run. The problem is I can run it once but scheduling 'blizzard' to run again has no effect, even with the correct input.

Comment: What's your desired output? Something like "I want to shoot 5 snowballs after a player right-clicks with a stone shovel in their hand". Have you looked into `plugin.getScheduler().scheduleSyncDelayedTask()`?

Comment: Blizzard drops a snowball randomly around the player every tick when player right clicks with a hoe in their hand. I know how to use Runnables but apparently BukkitRunnables are better.

Comment: Until canceled? Around every player? Snowballs start dropping around players when they join? Please be more descriptive, it'll really help us help you :)

Comment: edited above question for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `Bukkit` does not allow runnables to be rescheduled even after they are cancelled. If you learned about `Thread`s then you will remember that when a `Thread` is terminated, it can not be restarted. `Bukkit` follows this same logic when it comes to `Runnable` instances. A terminated (cancelled) `Runnable` can not be restarted. You must create a new `Runnable` instance if you wish to have that event occur again.

To have a `Runnable` run multiple times, you are on the right track. The `BukkitScheduler.runTaskTimer` method will run a task repeatedly until it is cancelled. If in your `Listener` you run `Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskTimer(Main.plugin, new Blizzard(), 0, 1);` your `Blizzard` object will run repeatedly until it cancels itself. (You can also use `blizzard.runTaskTimer(Main.plugin, 0, 1);` from within the `Blizzard` constructor to automatically schedule the `Runnable` when it is created.)

If you keep an internal counter for how many times it has run, and increment that timer every `run()` method, you can cancel your `Runnable` after it has run a certain amount of times.

Comment: That seems like a highly wasteful use of an object. I know that objects implementing Runnable can be canceled and rescheduled without creation of a new object, it is only objects that extend BukkitRunnable that seem to have this "non-reschedulable" behavior.

Comment: Looking at the source for `BukkitRunnable`, you would have to overwrite the runTask methods anyway. They check the taskId to see if it's -1 (unassigned) before allowing the runnable to be started, but there is no way to change the taskId back to -1 after that point. The `cancel()` should do that, but it doesn't and there is so mutator method to fix it yourself without reflection. Either you overwrite all the runTask methods, or use a basic runnable like I stated which doesn't involve overwriting core methods that may change in the future.